# Cubic Casimir for $su(3)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, unitary-matrices

I'm trying to figure out the form of the Casimir operators for $su(3)$. According to Racah's theorem, this group has two independent Casimir operators that can be constructed from its generators. The first one is easy to find: using the Gell-Mann matrices $\lambda_i,\ i=1,...8\ $ as generators, it can be written as

$$
C_1 = \sum_{i=1}^8 \lambda_i^2
$$

However, I'm struggling to construct the second one. In $\textit{The Lie Algebras su(N). An introduction}$ (section 4.11), Walter Pfeifer writes that $C_2$ is given by $C_2 = C_1(2C_1 - 11/6)$, and that this operator can be transformed so that it is expressed as sum of products of three $\lambda_i$'s. However, this Casimir operator is not independent from $C_1$ (in fact, it is completely determined by it). So, is this expression correct? If not, how can one construct the missing Casimir operator for $su(3)$?

Comment: Answer now clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the quadratic and cubic Casimirs are independent; why should one be talking about them?  As a general formula, the formula relating the two Casimirs (4.81) in Pfeifer is not general at all! However, he says, explicitly, it is *only for the fundamental representation*, half the Gell-Mann matrices, λ/2!

The general statements are
$$\hat{C}_1=\sum_k   \hat{F_k}   \hat{F_k}  \qquad  \qquad  \hat{C}_2=\sum_{jkl}d_{jkl}    \hat{F_j} \hat{F_k} \hat{F_l}  ~.$$

From Freudenthal's formula, for irrep $D(p,q)$, their respective eigenvalues are
$$ {C}_1 = (p^2+q^2+3p+3q+pq)/3 \\
  {C}_2 =(p-q)(3+p+2q)(3+q+2p)/18 . $$

The second Casimir eigenvalue is an odd function of the Dynkin representation indices, p,q, whilst the first one is an even function! See, e.g., [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Casimir_operators).

- check that, indeed, the equality  between the two you provide is satisfied for the D(1,0), the triplet ("one quark") representation, ***only***!

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that the form of the second Casimir of $SU(3)$ as constructed from the Gell-Mann Matrices is:

$$
d^{abc}T^aT^bT^c
$$

Where $T^a = \frac{\lambda^a}{2}$ (Sorry but as a physicist this is the basis I am the most familiar with) and $d^{abc}$ are the symmetric symbols, defined as $2 \, Tr(\{T^a,T^b\}T^c)$.

Sadly I don't remember the proof that this product actually commutes with all the $T^d$ and is therefore a Casimir. I tried doing it before writing this answer but couldn't make it work. I hope that my answer revitalizes this question and someone can direct the both of us to a proof.

P.S. I used Einstein's summation notation in my answer, i later saw that you didn't, i hope this notation isn't unfamiliar to you, just assume that avery repeated index is summed.